# Unifying multiple vscode debug configs into one

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a project with the following folder structure:

```
server
    somepackage
        src
            subpackage
                file.ts
        test
            subpackage
                file.spec.ts
    someotherpackage
        src
            file1.ts
        test
            file1.spec.ts
.vscode/launch.json
```

If I want to be able to debug the current file, in .vscode/launch.json, I need to create two configs with `"TS_NODE_PROJECT": "${fileDirname}/../tsconfig.json"` and `"TS_NODE_PROJECT": "${fileDirname}/tsconfig.json",` and to debug we will need to choose the appropriate config in the vscode debugger. Is there a way to do this with a single config. Can I say: TS_NODE_PROJECT = dir1/tsconfig.json and if it does not exist then it is dir2/tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) you can create part of a property based on the file path

```json
....

    "TS_NODE_PROJECT": "${fileDirname}${input:bypath}/tsconfig.json"

....

  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "bypath",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
      "args": {
        "/somepackage/": "",
        "/someotherpackage/": "/.."
      }
    }
  ]
```